# How do I reference WebComponent instances?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I would like to pass a reference to WebComponent instances created in markup to the WebComponent dart class. For instance:

html:

```
<element name="x-container>
  <template iterate="x in xs">
    <x-content-elem>
      <x-item item="{{x}}" top-container="{{lexical-scoped-ref-to-container}}">
    </x-content-elem>
</template>
...
```

I'm looking for a way to get a reference to x-container to the x-item.top-container property. The main thing is x-item might be nested in some complicated way so doing dynamic lookup could be difficult or not very robust.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the DOM to find the parent element. Something like this should work.

From inside of x-item:

```
Container container = this.parent.xtag;
```

A custom element acts like a node on the page. The `elem.xtag` getter returns the Dart object that backs the node on the page.

If there are other elements in-between, you can can still use CSS queries to find elements that you are looking for.

Comment: More importantly, is there anyway to reference the container in the HTML file with lexical scoping rules? Looking up ancestors in code is not quite what I want.

Comment: Why won't `this.parent` work for you? You can do that from the Dart class for your custom element. Maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: this.parent is evaluated at runtime and therefore has dynamic scoping rules. It refers to the parent at runtime. I'm looking for something that has lexical scoping rules.